# How do I add GameCenter to my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to save the high score to the user's GameCenter and also let the user compare his/her high score with others's using the leaderboard. How do I put this into my app - AppDelegate?

Answer (score 1):

Official guides, tutorials and videos.

https://developer.apple.com/game-center/

Other good tutorials

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-game-center-achievements-and-leaderboards-part-1--mobile-5701

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/game-center-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-part-12